# extracting vs testing an archive?

Tags: extract, file-archiver

is there any difference between extracting an archive vs testing it?

I'm writing a batch script and if archive testing assumes extraction in the background then I'm planning to extract only and capture errors if any without testing prior to extracting.

using 7zip command line utility.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different between extracting and archive and testing it.  The testing is a feature to validate the archive without extracting.

When extracting the archive, you're actually taking to contents from the archive and placing it in to the space you specify.